# Advantages of interface implements in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm new to GraphQL.

```
// using interface
interface User {
  name: String
}

type UserDetail implements User {
 name: String
 email: String
}

// just type
type User {
  name: String
}

type UserDetail {
 name: String
 email: String
}
```

There is duplicated field `name` in interface `User` and type `UserDetail`.

I thought `UserDetail` doesn't have to include `name`.

I couldn't find detailed information of interface.

Why do I use interface, implements instead of just type?

And I want to know differences of using interface and type, advantages of using interface.

Please comment any advices.

Comment: Have you read the graphql docs about them?  https://graphql.org/learn/schema/  Or is this question related to performance?